# Adding properties until in react-native-countdown-component with react native state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have a problem with adding value with state to properties until in react-native-countdown-component. I already state the **waktu** with null, and then i setState the variables **waktu** from fetch data api. when i running with the console log the state, the value show null at 3 times after that the value from setState show. [click here for see the value in console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkGRm.png)

then my component countdown i set to variable state the value for **until** read by null and not from data from api. How can i solve this? when the screen appear the countdown will play with value from data not null. here's my code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, AsyncStorage, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Image, Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {Container, Content, Header, Left, Right, Button, Icon} from 'native-base'
import HTMLView from 'react-native-htmlview'
import CountDown from 'react-native-countdown-component';
import Footers from '../components/Footers'
const{width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')

export default class TryOut extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      getToken : null,
      getNama : null,
      soal : [],
      TotalSoal : null,
      index:0,
      jawaban: [],
      indexJawaban : 0,
      terjawab : [],
      indexTerjawab : 0,
      value :'',

      to_id : null,
      to_nilai : null,
      id_jawab : null,
      // waktu : null
    };
  }

  state ={
    waktu : 0
  }

  componentDidMount = async() =>{
    const nilai = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
    this.setState({getToken:nilai})
    fetch('https://api.bintangpelajar.com/api/user/profile_data',{
        method:'post',
        headers:{
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            token : nilai
        })
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson =>{
            if(responseJson){
                this.setState({getNama: responseJson.data.damping_nama})
            }else{
                console.log('ada yang salah')
            }
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error)
        })
      this.getSoal()
      // this.isNullJawaban
  }

  getSoal =()=>{
    fetch('http://unnamed48.ccug.gunadarma.ac.id:9091/api/user/soal',{
        method:'post',
        headers:{
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          token:this.state.getToken,
          studi:"penalaran umum"
        })
    }).then(res => res.json())
      .then(getData =>{
          // console.log(getData.time)
          if(getData){
              this.setState({
                  soal : getData.data,
                  TotalSoal : getData.count,
                  to_id: getData.to_id,
                  to_nilai : getData.to_nilai,
                  id_jawab : getData.id_jawab,
                  waktu : getData.time
              })
              
              for(let i = 0; i< getData.count; i++){
                const jawab = this.state.soal[i]
                const coba = {
                  no_soal : i+1,
                  id_soal : jawab && jawab.soal_id,
                  jawaban : ''
                }
                this.state.jawaban.splice(i,0,coba)
              }
          }
      }).catch(error =>{
          console.log(error)
      })
}

  submitJawab(index, no, id_soal, jawaban){
    // alert('indeks ke-'+index)
    const coba = {
      no_soal : no,
      id_soal : id_soal,
      jawaban : jawaban
    }
    if(this.state.jawaban[index] === undefined){
    this.state.jawaban.splice(index,0, coba)
    this.setState((state)=>{
      const terBaru = [...state.terjawab]

      terBaru[index] = jawaban
      return{terjawab: terBaru}
    })
    }else{
      this.setState((state)=>{
        const jawabBaru = [...state.jawaban]

        jawabBaru[index] = coba
        return{jawaban: jawabBaru}
      })
      this.setState((state)=>{
        const terBaru = [...state.terjawab]

        terBaru[index] = jawaban
        return{terjawab: terBaru}
      })
    }
  }

  cek = ()=>{
    alert('jawabannya : ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.jawaban))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.jawaban))
  }

  nextSoal(index, no, id_soal){
    this.setState({
      index:(this.state.index + 1) % this.state.soal.length,
      indexJawaban:(this.state.indexJawaban + 1) % this.state.jawaban.length,
      indexTerjawab:(this.state.indexTerjawab + 1) % this.state.terjawab.length,
    })
}

prevSoal = ()=>{
    this.setState({
      index:(this.state.index - 1) % this.state.soal.length,
      indexJawaban:(this.state.indexJawaban - 1) % this.state.jawaban.length,
      indexTerjawab:(this.state.indexTerjawab - 1) % this.state.terjawab.length,
    })
}
  
  render() {
    // var time = this.state.waktu * 60
    const {waktu} = this.state
    const item = this.state.soal[this.state.index]
    const a = item && item.soal_opsi_a
    const b = item && item.soal_opsi_b
    const c = item && item.soal_opsi_c
    const d = item && item.soal_opsi_d
    const e = item && item.soal_opsi_e
    const no = this.state.index + 1
    const id_soal = item && item.soal_id
    const jawaban = []
    console.log(waktu)
    // jawaban.splice(0,0,a,b,c,d,e)
    jawaban.splice(0,0,{pg:'A',ket:a},{pg:'B',ket:b},{pg:'C',ket:c},{pg:'D',ket:d},{pg:'E',ket:e})
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                <Left>
                    <View style={{flexDirection:'row', marginTop:'5%'}}>
                        <Button transparent>
                            <Icon name="arrow-back" />
                        </Button>
                        <Text style={{color:'white', marginTop:'12%', marginLeft:'5%', fontWeight:'bold', fontSize:14}}>Kembali</Text>
                    </View>
                </Left>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Right>
                <Text style={{fontFamily:'Arial', fontWeight:'bold', fontSize:14, margin:'5%', color:'#fff'}}>Halo, {this.state.getNama}</Text>
                {/* a onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('edit')} */}
                <Button transparent>
                    <Image source={require('../assets/icons/user.png')} style={{width:30, height:30}}/>
                </Button>
            </Right>
        </Header>
        <Content>
          <View style={{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', marginTop:height*0.05}}>
            <CountDown
              size={20}
              until={waktu}
              onFinish={() => alert('Finished')}
              digitStyle={{backgroundColor: '#FFF', borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#04458F'}}
              digitTxtStyle={{color: '#04458F'}}
              timeLabelStyle={{color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bold'}}
              separatorStyle={{color: '#04458F'}}
              timeToShow={['H', 'M', 'S']}
              timeLabels={{m: null, s: null}}
              showSeparator
            />
          </View>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between', alignItems:'center', marginTop:height*0.03}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 16, marginLeft: width*0.04}}>{no}/{this.state.TotalSoal}</Text>
            {/* {this.state.index != this.state.soal.length-1 ? (this.state.index ==0 ? (<Text>lewat</Text>) : (<View><Text>Lewat</Text><Text>Lanjut</Text></View>)) : (<Text>finis</Text>)  } */}

            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', marginRight: width*0.04}}>
            {this.state.index != this.state.soal.length-1 ? (this.state.index ==0 ? (<Text style={{fontSize: 16, textDecorationLine:'underline', color:'#04458F'}} onPress={()=>this.nextSoal(this.state.index, no, id_soal)}>Lewati</Text>) : (<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 16, marginRight:width*0.02, textDecorationLine:'underline', color:'#04458F'}} onPress={this.prevSoal}>Soal Sebelumnya</Text>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 16, textDecorationLine:'underline', color:'#04458F'}} onPress={()=>this.nextSoal(this.state.index, no, id_soal)}>Lewati</Text>
              </View>)) : (<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}><Text style={{fontSize: 16, marginRight:width*0.02, textDecorationLine:'underline', color:'#04458F'}} onPress={this.prevSoal}>Soal Sebelumnya</Text>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 16, textDecorationLine:'underline', color:'#04458F'}} onPress={this.cek}>Finish</Text></View>)  }
            {/* {this.state.index ==0 ? (<Text style={{fontSize: 16, textDecorationLine:'underline', color:'#04458F'}} onPress={()=>this.nextSoal(this.state.index, no, id_soal)}>Lewati</Text>) : (<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 16, marginRight:width*0.02, textDecorationLine:'underline', color:'#04458F'}} onPress={this.prevSoal}>Soal Sebelumnya</Text>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 16, textDecorationLine:'underline', color:'#04458F'}} onPress={()=>this.nextSoal(this.state.index, no, id_soal)}>Lewati</Text>
              </View>) } */}
            </View>
          </View>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 16, marginLeft: width*0.04, marginTop:height*0.03}}>Pertanyaan</Text>
          {/* <Button title='jawaban tersubmit' onPress={this.cek}/> */}
          <ScrollView style={{marginTop:height*0.03}}>
            <View style={{justifyContent:'center', alignSelf:'center'}}>
              <Image source={require('../assets/image/banner2.png')} style={{width:width*0.7, height:height*0.25}} resizeMode='stretch' />
            </View>
            <HTMLView value={item && item.soal_pertanyaan} style={{margin : width*0.1, textAlign:'justify'}}/>
            {/* <Text style={{margin : width*0.1, textAlign:'justify'}}>{item && item.soal_pertanyaan}</Text> */}
            {/* <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}> */}
              {jawaban.map(opsi=>{
                  return(
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={()=>this.submitJawab(this.state.index,no, id_soal, opsi.pg)}
                        // style={{backgroundColor:'blue'}}
                      >
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                      
                      <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
                        <View style={styles.circle}>
                          <Text style={{position:'absolute', fontSize:24}}>{opsi.pg}</Text>
                          {this.state.terjawab[this.state.index] === opsi.pg && <View style={styles.checkedCircle}></View>}
                        </View>
                        <HTMLView value={opsi.ket} style={{justifyContent:'center', alignSelf:'center', marginRight:width*0.2, marginLeft:width*0.05}}/>
                        {/* <Text style={{justifyContent:'center', alignSelf:'center', marginRight:width*0.2, marginLeft:width*0.05}}>{opsi.ket}</Text> */}
                      </View>
                    </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                      // <TouchableOpacity style={{justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', flexDirection:'row' }} onPress={()=>this.submitJawab(this.state.index,no, id_soal, opsi)}>
                      //   <View style={styles.circle}></View> {opsi}
                      //   <View style={{flexDirection:'row', margin:10, backgroundColor:'grey', width:width*0.7}} >
                      //   {this.state.terjawab[this.state.index] === opsi && <View style={styles.checkedCircle}></View>}
                      //     <Text style={{justifyContent:'center', alignSelf:'center', marginLeft:width*0.04}}>{opsi}</Text>
                      //   </View>
                      // </TouchableOpacity>
                  )
              })}
            {/* </View> */}
          </ScrollView>
        </Content>
        <Footers/>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  checkedCircle: {
      width: 48,
      height: 48,
      borderRadius: 24,
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      opacity:0.5
},
circle: {
  height: 48,
  width: 48,
  borderRadius: 24,
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: '#000',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  marginLeft:width*0.07,
  marginTop:height*0.02,
  marginBottom:height*0.02
},
buttonContainer: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'center',
  margin:width*0.04,
  backgroundColor:'#fff',
  borderRadius:10,
  borderWidth: 1
  // backgroundColor:'grey'
},
})
```

thank you for helping me.